# Blessed Anne Catherine Emmerich's Prophecy on the Two Popes

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, prophecy, papacy, pope-francis

I would like to know the source (a book, I presume) that speaks about Blessed Anne Catherine Emmerich's "Prophecy of the two popes.''

Every online site that I recall, which speaks about it, has plenty to say but gives no actual source. See, for example, the articles "[Blessed Anne Catherine Emmerich Prophecy on The Two Popes](https://v-catholic.com/signs-of-our-times/blessed-anne-catherine-emmerich-prophecy-on-the-two-popes/)" or "[Anne Catherine Emmerich and the Two Popes](https://onepeterfive.com/anne-catherine-emmerich-and-the-two-popes/)".

I thought, perhaps, that I might find it in "[The Life And Revelations Of Anne Catherine Emmerich](https://ia800608.us.archive.org/16/items/TheLifeAndRevelationsOfAnneCatherineEmmerichComplete/TheLifeAndRevelationsOfAnneCatherineEmmerich.pdf)".

But a search of "two popes" or "heretics of every kind" brings up nothing.

Does anyone know what the source of the "Two Popes" prophecy is, and if so, where I might find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from her 13 May 1820 prophecy, [*The Life and Revelations of Anne Catherine Emmerich* vol. 2](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4146) pp. 227ff.

Excerpt: Yves Dupont, [*Catholic Prophecy*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4444) p. 60:

> ¶53.1 *May 13, 1820.* “I saw also the relationship between the two popes … I saw how baleful would be the consequences of this false church. I saw it increase in size; heretics of every kind came into the city (of Rome). The local clergy grew lukewarm, and I saw a great darkness … Then, the vision seemed to extend on every side. Whole Catholic communities were being oppressed, harassed, confined, and deprived of their freedom. I saw many churches close down, great miseries everywhere, wars and bloodshed. A wild and ignorant mob took to violent action. But it did not last long.
>
> ¶53.2 “Once more I saw that the Church of Peter was undermined by a plan evolved by the secret sect, while storms were damaging it. But I saw also that help was coming when distress had reached its peak. I saw again the Blessed Virgin ascend on the Church and spread her mantle [over it]. I saw a Pope who was at once gentle, and very firm … I saw a great renewal, and the Church rose high in the sky.”

Comment: Thank you most kindly for this answer.